# Can a Linux system have two IP's Simultaneously?

Tags: apache-httpd, ip, raspbian, hostname

Recently I installed apache2 on Raspbian and after end of installation I entered the following cmd and got two IP's.

```
$ hostname -I
192.168.1.17 192.168.1.24
```

Of this, I have been using the IP ending in 17 from beginning. But I have never seen the one with 24. Can I use them both to access my RPi or each one present only for a specific use. Like 24 only for apache ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hostname -I` doesn't work here (openSUSE 13.2) but there is no problem with one host using several IP addresses. That is obviously possible by having several network adapters but you can have several addresses per interface (aliases) and even several interfaces per hardware NIC.

The usual way to see the network configuration is `ip addr show`.

Answer (score 0):

The command **hostname -I** gives back all IP-addresses that are currently configured on your system with exception to local-link addresses for IPv6 or on your loopback interfaces. So yes you could use 192.168.1.24 as well to access your site if Apache is configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When you use :

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen# ip addr show up
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:03:73:60:b4:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.14/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.1.21/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary eth0:1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1a03:73ff:fe60:b44e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I set up alias IP for eth0 , you have to find IPs of ethernet of set on the given ethernet. Or you can use:

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen# ifconfig 

    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:03:73:60:b4:4e  
              inet addr:192.168.1.14  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::1a03:73ff:fe60:b44e/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:101110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:81804 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:89999660 (85.8 MiB)  TX bytes:10808197 (10.3 MiB)

    eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:03:73:60:b4:4e  
              inet addr:192.168.1.21  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

*It's better to don't use alias IP and use original IP.*